# How to append an element to a div which is without id

Tags: javascript

I want to use javascript to add a link inside a div, this div doesn't have id , it does has a class though:

```
<div class="details">
  <div class="filename">test.xml</div>
  <div class="uploaded">25/12/2012</div>

  <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>

  <div class="compat-meta"></div>
</div>
```

How to add a link inside the "details" div and above the "delete" link? 
The link I want to add is:

```
<a href="#edit_link" class="edit">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Will jQuery be acceptable to use? Otherwise you will get a lot of getElementsByClassName and insertNode code which may not work in all browsers

Comment: anything is fine as long as I can print the script in webpage footer

Comment: Have you try something ?

Comment: If this is the only thing you need to do, jQuery is a bit overkill IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go for jquery, it's simple and clean.

you can grab any element with a particular class say

```
<div class="className" ></div>
```

like this

```
<script>
$('.className'); 
</script>
```

now you want to append someother element just before the anchor having `delete`   class, well than you can do this:

```
$('.delete').before('<a href="#edit_link" class="edit">Edit</a>');
```

there are other methods also to append an element inside any other element or dom

```
 1. $('.className').append('<div> i will be appended at the bottom of this element</div>');
 2. $('.className').after('<div> i will be appended right after this element</div>');
```

for using jquery, you will need its api, directly use [this](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js) link in your page or, download the latest jQuery api and use it.
its simpler and easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
function hasClass(element, className) {
    var s = ' ' + element.className + ' ';
    return s.indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') !== -1;
}

 /**
 * from: http://www.dustindiaz.com/getelementsbyclass
 */
function $class(className, context, tag) {
    var classElements = [],
        context = context || document,
        tag = tag || '*';

    var els = context.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    for (var i = 0, ele; ele = els[i]; i++) {
        if (hasClass(ele, className)) {
            classElements.push(ele);
        }
    }
    return classElements;
}
```

then use the `$class('delete')` to locate the elements, and then prepend new elements

Comment: sorry, I am below entry level in javascript.  how to use $class('delete') and prepend new?

Comment: well, then just follow another answer with jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037048/how-to-append-an-element-to-a-div-which-is-without-id/14037143#answer-14037266

Answer (score 0):

It's always best to search by id, it is most efficient. However if it comes to it, you may find elements by class or tag name as well.

I recommend using jQuery, and changing the existing  tag you have:

```
$('a').attr('href', '#edit_link').text('Edit').removeClass('delete').addClass('edit');
```

If it is not possible to add an id to the element you're finding, find an element somewhere higher in the tree that has an id, and go from there:

```
$('#someHigherId > div > a')...
```

Comment: the delete link is needed, I need to add an edit link above it

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery:

```
$('div.details a.delete').before('<a href="#edit_link" class="edit">Edit</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure JavaScript:

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('details')[0],
    deleteLink = div.getElementsByClassName('delete')[0],
    editLink = document.createElement('a');

editLink.textContent = 'Edit';
editLink.className = 'edit';
editLink.href = '#edit_link';

div.insertBefore(editLink, deleteLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do it using javascript like this

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addtext(what){
        if (document.createTextNode){
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.setAttribute('href', '#edit_link');
            link.setAttribute('id', 'edit');
            link.setAttribute('class', 'edit');
            document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].appendChild(link)
            document.getElementById("edit").innerHTML = what;
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="details" id="mydiv" onClick="addtext('Edit')">
    <div class="filename">test.xml</div>
    <div class="uploaded">25/12/2012</div>

    <a href="#"  class="delete">Delete</a>


    <div class="compat-meta"></div>
</div>
```